# Left join not functioning

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have here query that needs to retrieve the employeeid, name, startdate, period, manager, bussinessline, unit, subunit and status of an employee

Employee table is joined to other tables and I provided the employeeid of the employees I need to have my list and I left joined it to the other table so that if the employee doesn't have the values it will only return null. I dont get what I expected. Where did I go wrong?

```
 select employee.id as 'Employee ID', concat_ws(' ',employee.first_name, employee.last_name) as 'Name', 
date_started as 'Start date', os_form.os_event_id as 'Period', 
(select concat_ws(' ',employee.first_name, employee.last_name) from employee where id = os_form.created_by) as 'Manager', 
business_line.name as 'Business_line', unit.name as 'Unit', sub_unit.name as 'Sub Unit', os_form.status as 'Status'
from employee
LEFT JOIN os_form 
    ON (os_form.employee_id = employee.id and os_form.employee_id 
    IN (110013
,110015
,110002
,110042
,110057
,110065
,110060
,110062
,110092
,110072
,110095
,110100
,110104
,110106
,110107
,110109
,110077
,110114
,110117
,110121
,110123
,110073
,110128
,110138
,110147
,110153
,110162
,110173
,110178
,110183
,110211
,110215
,110216
,110218
,110219
,110224
,110226
,110230
,110245
,110249
,110257
,110260
,110262
,110264
,110266
,110268
,110269
,110272
,110275
,120076
,120083
,120090
,120099
,120095
,120101
,120108
,120109
,120110
,120112
,120119
,120127
,120128
,120132
,120133
,120134
,120145
,120146
,120142
,130010
,130012
,130016
,130017
,130018
,130020
,130021
,130006
,130034
,130035
,130038
,130041
,130029
,130046
,130047
,130056
,130013
,130027
,130028
,130030
,130037
,130040
,130043
,130044
,130048
,130049
,130054
,130055
,130031
,130050
,130064
,130065
,130084
,130092
,130094
,130095
,130096
,130097
,130098
,130099
,130105
,130051
,130059
,130111
,130112
,130115
,130116
,130127
,130136
,130109
,140002
,140105
,140158
,140178
,140304
,140171
,140358
,140352
,140354
,140356
,140401
,140407
,140410
,140411
,140409
,140412
,140417
,140418
,140419
,140422
,140423
,150003
,150132
,150141
,150143
,150167
,150193
,150199))
left join business_line on os_form.business_line_id = business_line.id
left join unit on unit.id = os_form.unit_id
left join sub_unit on sub_unit.id = os_form.sub_unit_id
WHERE os_event_id = 2015
group by employee.id
```

Comment: left join all other joins as well

Comment: change the were condition to and and put in under his table

Comment: Also: Since os_form.employee_id = employee.id, and you want a left join, use: where employee.id in (...) instead of os_form.employee_id in (...)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with `WHERE` statement. More precisely, it's the fact that you check whether `os_form.employee_id` is exists on a list of identifiers.

You should either move that check into `LEFT JOIN ... ON ()`

```
LEFT JOIN os_form 
    ON (os_form.employee_id = employee.id and os_form.employee_id IN (110013,110015, ...))
```

or keep it in `WHERE`and check for NULL as well:

```
WHERE (os_form.employee_id IS NULL or os_form.employee_id IN
(
  110013,110015,110002,110042,110057,110065,110060,110062,110092,110072,110095,110100,110104,110106,110107,110109,110077,110114,110117,110121,110123,110073,110128,110138,110147,110153,110162,110173,110178,110183,110211,110215,110216,110218,110219,110224,110226,110230,110245,110249,110257,110260,110262,110264,110266,110268,110269,110272,110275,120076,120083,120090,120099,120095,120101,120108,120109,120110,120112,120119,120127,120128,120132,120133,120134,120145,120146,120142,130010,130012,130016,130017,130018,130020,130021,130006,130034,130035,130038,130041,130029,130046,130047,130056,130013,130027,130028,130030,130037,130040,130043,130044,130048,130049,130054,130055,130031,130050,130064,130065,130084,130092,130094,130095,130096,130097,130098,130099,130105,130051,130059,130111,130112,130115,130116,130127,130136,130109,140002,140105,140158,140178,140304,140171,140358,140352,140354,140356,140401,140407,140410,140411,140409,140412,140417,140418,140419,140422,140423,150003,150132,150141,150143,150167,150193,150199
))
```

You may also need LEFT JOIN all other joins as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering but sad to say, still not working. 
check my edit thanks

Answer (score 0):

SINCE YOU POY THE CONDITION UNDER THE WHERE

TRY THIS

```
select employee.id as 'Employee ID', concat_ws(' ',employee.first_name, employee.last_name) as 'Name', 
date_started as 'Start date', os_form.os_event_id as 'Period', 
(select concat_ws(' ',employee.first_name, employee.last_name) from employee where id = os_form.created_by) as 'Manager', 
business_line.name as 'Business_line', unit.name as 'Unit', sub_unit.name as 'Sub Unit', os_form.status as 'Status'
from employee
left join os_form on os_form.employee_id = employee.id
and os_form.employee_id in
(
110013
,110015
,110002
150193
,150199
)
join business_line on os_form.business_line_id = business_line.id
join unit on unit.id = os_form.unit_id
join sub_unit on sub_unit.id = os_form.sub_unit_id
and os_event_id = 2015
group by employee.id
```